# How to pass and receive data using router.navigate with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to pass and read data using Angular `Route.navigate` ,

On one component I have

```
this._router.navigate(["dashboard",{ queryParams: { page: 1 }}],
```

On Dashboard component I have

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        let page = +params['page'] || 0;
        console.log(page);
      });
  }
```

But this always return **0**

Am I doing anything wrong?

My `ng --version` is

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
node: 6.3.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 4.1.1
@angular/compiler: 4.1.1
@angular/core: 4.1.1
@angular/forms: 4.1.1
@angular/http: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.1
@angular/router: 4.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.1
IPLCEWKS01167:routeTest iplcewks01167$
```

Answer (score 2):

`queryParams` should be the second parameter for `navigate`.

replace this line

```
this._router.navigate(["dashboard",{ queryParams: { page: 1 }}];
```

to

```
this._router.navigate(["dashboard"], { queryParams: { page: 1 }});
```

Comment: I dont know the reason , but this is not working. But this works :: this._router.navigate(["dashboard",{ page: 1 }] :: this.sub = this._route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        let page = +params['page'] || 0;
        console.log(page);
      });

Comment: @raju yes, they are two different way. when using `queryParams`, it should be setted to the second parameter.

Comment: @raju and the previous one is syntax for `params` and the second is for `queryParams`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :-**

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', { queryParams: { page: 1 }} ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{ path: 'a4/:message', component:  Angular4Component, data:{ ping:'passedvia router'}}
```

fetch it in the component using `this.message = this.route.snapshot.params['message'];`

this is the file in which it is used in the repo .

```
https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/angular4/angular4.component.ts
```

The working example for the same - https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Answer (score 0):

Angular 7.2.0 introduced new way of passing the data when navigating between routed components without the data being a part of the query string.

**Sending the data**

```
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
    goToComponentB(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['routePath'], {state: {data: {...}}});
    }
}
```

**Receiving the data**

You can read the data from browser’s history object in the constructor:

```
constructor(){
   Console.log(history.state.data);
}
```

Reference - https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255